# Firebase Cloud Function is calling the wrong collection even though it is referencing another path

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

```
exports.requestPayment = functions.firestore.document('/Orders/{documentId}').onCreate((change, context) => {
   console.log(change.ref);
   return;
});
```

This prints out:

```
...
"_path": {
    "segments": [
      "Payments",
      "Cm4rXRPnWnOpZNryWRN4"
    ],
    ...
  }
```

The function prints out the wrong collection and document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to change the the documentPath in the actual settings of the Google Cloud Functions. When you press edit you can change the path.